# Socialite - after successful login unable to log into Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-socialite

I am trying to set up login with Google using Laravel and socialite. I've set everything up to go to the Google login page and redirect me back to the application. However, when I'm redirected I always end up on the "login" page and not the "home" page. After successfully logging in with Google I'm not logged into my Laravel app. What is wrong?

```
/**
 * Obtain the user information from Google.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('/login');
    }

    // check if they're an existing user
    $existingUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();

    if($existingUser){
        // log them in
        auth()->login($existingUser, true);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $newUser                  = new User;
        $newUser->name            = $user->name;
        $newUser->email           = $user->email;
        $newUser->google_id       = $user->id;
        $newUser->avatar          = $user->avatar;
        $newUser->avatar_original = $user->avatar_original;
        $newUser->save();

        auth()->login($newUser, true);
    }
    return redirect()->to('/home');

}
```

Despite the calls to login a user I am not logged in when redirected back to the app. How can I make sure that after logging in with Google I'm logged in to the Laravel app?

**Update**

It turns out when the $user variable comes back from Google I am getting a `InvalidStateException`

[image]

The try catch block actually throws an exception. If I dd the exception it looks like:

[image]

It turns out what was breaking it for me was in my **.env** file I had:

`SESSION_DOMAIN=http://localhost:8000`

Removing this line fixed the issue!

Comment: can you insure that your callback `handleProviderCallback` is actually getting called?, try to log something from there

Comment: It is I can dd() the $user variable with all the info from google

Comment: please post your routes file.

Comment: Problem is in else block of creating new user. You are attempting to dedicate values like $user->email although you don't have ones.

Comment: Is the new user created in your database?

Comment: The user is created in my database @Jonathon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `SESSION_DOMAIN` from your **.env** file